# Android Studio Aapt2 error

Tags: java, android

I downloaded the 3.x version of android studio and got the error below.

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Then I tried the following method.

**android.enableaapt2 = false**

At the moment I get an error like this.

> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use '**android.enableAapt2 = true**' to remove this warning.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018 ..

I tried a method like this.

**android.enableaapt2 = true**

At the moment I get an error like below. What do I have to do with you?

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Comment: We need the build log to find the real errors from AAPT2. You can get them by going to the project's directory in a terminal of your choice (or using the Terminal window in Android Studio) and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug". Post the output of that command in the question and we can work together on figuring this out. :)